# Paypal Sandbox is showing Incorrect Email

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am doing express checkout transaction and when I am logging in to my Sandbox Account it gives me an error:

> This Sandbox email address is not available. Please enter another
>   email address

[image: 1) first screen is showing the login page of paypal]
[image: 2) second is redirecting the page which has error]

Comment: This question doesn't have anything to do with C# or asp.net.

Comment: Started to see the same problem too..... Since they rolled out some of their REST API stuff this seems to have become broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Paypal have launched new API.
Also only SDK's beta version available.
For now Sandbox account is down so you can't access or test using them.

Answer (score 0):

I think paypal is giving you the correct error message, sandbox will only allow you to login with the email address that is related to your sandbox credential email.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the address in the address bar is reflecting the sandbox URL and not the live site URL.  Also you might try clearing your cookies and cache prior to opening up your browser and logging into developer.paypal.com.  There have been some issues that are causing login issues and clearing cookies and cache has resolved some of these.